# Getting table elements in same row with jquery

Tags: php, jquery, sql, html-table

I am really confused about how I can do this. I need to get the value of two `<td>` when one is selected. For example, below let's say I select the td with id=monthly of $550 dollars. I need to get the age and excess that corresponds with that price. I hope this makes sense. SO in the example of selecting $550 I need jQuery to get the values age(18-24) and excess($1000). I then will take these two values and insert into mysql as noted below. Is there anyway I can do this with either jQuery or PHP? I am open to ideas.

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <td width="67"></td>
    <td width="102" id="excess">$1000</td>
    <td width="102" id="excess">$2000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="67" id="age">18-24</td>
    <td width="102" id="monthly">$550</td>
    <td width="102" id="monthly">$650</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td width="67" id="age">25-29</td>
    <td width="102" id="monthly">$750</td>
    <td width="102" id="monthly">$850</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

MYSQL(using the example above):

```
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET Monthly = '$550' WHERE Age = '18-24' AND Excess = '$1000'")or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have more than one element with the same `id`, `id` values (as the name suggests) **must** be unique. If you're trying to classify elements, use a `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. You cannot have more than one element with the same `id`, `id` values (as the name suggests) must be unique. If you're trying to classify elements, use a `class`. The rest of this answer assumes those `id` values have been changed to `class` names.

If I understand you, you want to handle clicks on cells with the `monthly` class and get the text of the first cell in the row along with the first cell in the column. This is easily done with jQuery ([live example](http://jsbin.com/irajev) | [source](http://jsbin.com/irajev/edit)):

```
$("td.monthly").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        firstCellInRow = $this.closest('tr').find('td').first(),
        firstCellInColumn = $this.closest('table').find('tr').first().find('td').eq($this.index());
    console.log("First cell in row: " + firstCellInRow.text());
    console.log("First cell in column: " + firstCellInColumn.text());
});
```

We find the first cell in the row by finding the row via [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest), then finding its first cell via [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find) and [`first`](http://api.jquery.com/first).

We find the first cell in the column by finding the table via `closest`, then getting the first row via `find` and `first`, then getting the [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index) of the clicked cell and finding the cell in the first row with the same index via [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq).

Comment: you are right about the ids... I was having a blonde moment. This works perfectly.. thank you soooo much for taking the time to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.monthly').bind('click', function()
{
    lstrMonth  = $(this).html();
    lstrAge    = $(this).parent().find('td:first').html();
    lnIndex    = $(this).parent().index($(this));
    lstrExcess = $(this).parent('table').find('tr:first td:nth-child('+ (lnIndex + 1) +')');

    // do ajax call to a php script which execute the query
    $.post('ajax/update.php', 
    {
        age:    lstrAge,
        excess: lstrExcess,
        month:  lstrMonth  
    },
    function(data) // success
    {
        // do whatever you want
    });
});
```

I think this will work, the PHP will simplified look like:

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE table SET Monthly = '".$_POST['month']."' WHERE Age = '".$_POST['age']."' AND Excess = '".$_POST['excess']."'")or die(mysql_error());
?>
```